# Read Data from XML Returned Data

Tags: php, xml

I am calling a xml file called signup.xml in PHP and in return, XML file returns me `<int>7962329</int>`. But I don't know how to fetch this in PHP variables and display in browser. Can somebody help me?

Comment: How do you read the XML-file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for instance. As you don't specify what your XML-file look like in your question I cannot give you an exact answer, but to give you some guidance you could do something like this to output the tagname and the content of each tag on the first level.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("yourfile.xml");

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
}
?>
```

The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) provide a lot of examples on basic usage of SimpleXML.

**Update**

With the updated info in the question, in your case the code would be something like:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("signup.xml");
$int = $xml->int;
echo $int;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php Domdocument

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument(); 
  $objDOM->load("test.xml"); //make sure path is correct 


  $note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("lon"); 
  // for each note tag, parse the document and get values for 
  // tasks and details tag. 

  foreach( $note as $value ) 
  { 
    $tasks = $value->getElementsByTagName("id"); 
    $task  = $tasks->item(0)->nodeValue; 


    $details = $value->getElementsByTagName("name"); 
    $detail  = $details->item(0)->nodeValue; 

    $notes = $value->getElementsByTagName("notes"); 
    $notes  = $notes->item(0)->nodeValue; 

    echo "$task :: $detail :: $notes <br>"; 
  }
```